# How do I see which dll a namespace is being imported from?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

I have an MVC 2 page. In it there is a declaration at the top...

```
<%@ Import Namespace="EDF.ESCS.CAFE.AppSDK.Web.Mvc.Html" %>
```

I want to investigate this namespace. I looked at the references in the project and its not obvious which reference because they have different names.

I want to find out which dll this is coming from? But how can I do this in visual studio?

I have got re-sharper but I would prefer to use just visual studio so I know for next time...

Answer (score 6):

There's not a one-to-one relationship between namespaces and references. Types under the same namespace may span over several assemblies.

If you use Visual Studio's object browser (Ctrl+Alt+J), you can view all the referenced types, either by namespace or reference. If you view by namespace, select a type within a namespace, then view by container, it'll bring you to the reference which contains it.